# Abstract Algebra book with exercise solutions recommendations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am new to studying abstract algebra (and math in general). I've been reading Gilligan and Pinter's books. I am trying to improve my understanding by doing exercises. However none of the books I am reading seem to come with exercise solutions.

Is there an abstract algebra book with lots of exercise with solutions?
I am confused as to why none of the math books come with complete exercise solutions. How do people verify that their answers are right.

Comment: I really love Pinter's book, but the lack of solutions is really disappointing. Checking if you are right is such an important step in learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple search on Google shows the following:

- Abstract Algebra Manual ( Problems and Solutions ) by Ayman Badawi
- http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/review/review.pdf
- http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~wclark/Elem_abs_alg.pdf
- https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~oh233/old/algebra1/book.pdf
- Schaum's Theory & Problems of Abstract Algebra by Joong Fang

Answer (score 5):

Gallian's book has selected exercises' solutions (apparently all the odd numbered ones)

Weiss's "First Course in Algebra and Number Theory" has lots of solutions

Whitesitt's "Principles of Modern Algebra" has many solutions

Krechmar's "A Problem Book in Algebra" (high school level) has *all* the solutions

Vinberg's "A Course in Algebra" has some solutions

Faddeev-Sominskii's "Problems in Higher Algebra" (high school-basic linear algebra) is all solutions

Gilbert's "Elements of Modern Algebra" has many solutions.

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have read contemporary abstract algebra by Gallian. Though I dont remember if it had exercises and solutions but the chapters of the book are written in a very easy to understand way. It gave me a good insight into group theory.

I dont know if it's the answer to your question but you can check the book out if it works for you.

Comment: I am currently reading that book, no that book doesn't come with solutions manual.

Comment: Later editions of Gallian's book have answers to odd numbered problems. There is a full solutons manual but it is hard to get, even harder to get an edition of the book and an edition of the solutions manual that match
.