# Good math books to solve questions in Algebra and General Topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a new master's student in mathematics. When I was studying for bachelor's, mathematic was only fun for me as my second major. I decided to study mathematics as a professional. I think I need to work more on my Topology and Abstract Algebra skills. I am familiar with subjects, and I just want good questions to solve. Are there any good books or documents that have problems in these courses?
If I want to learn from solving questions, what do you recommend?
I want to try to solve challenging questions and try to use things I studied. I think in this way I will learn those core courses better.
I have studied the introduction of topology from the Munkres and Abstract Algebra from Dummit.

Comment: This site has several book recommendations with exercises. For abstract algebra see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527167/abstract-algebra-book-with-exercise-solutions-recommendations/527362) and similar ones. The exercises in Dummit and Foot are also very good. I suppose you have tried them already?

Comment: Finite group theory by Isaacs has some dope problems in finite group theory.

Comment: Yes I had solved Dummit's questions when I was studying it. Actually. I want a book with only problems and no teaching.

Answer (score 3):

[Problem and solution of General Topology](http://xn--webducation-dbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Mortad-Mohammed-Hichem-Introductory-topology-exercises-and-solutions-World-Scientific-2017.pdf)

[ABSTRACT ALGEBRA PROBLEMS AND SOLUTIONS](https://www.ayman-badawi.com/Groups%20only%20Badawi-F-2.pdf)

Comment: Thanks...Do you know any other books for topology which is similar to the algebra book that you are recommended.  No definition and only questions.